# void function not printing because cant return value but when i make string or int function it print null or return value at the end automatically

Tags: class, dart, printing, return, void

New to dart, take following code as example, //void function doesnt work and int/string function either returns null that is printed or value return which is automatically printed as can be seen in the output.

```
class Microphones{
  String? name;
  String? color;
  int? model;
  String printEverything(){
    print(name);
    return " "; 
  }
  int? printint(){ 
    print(model); 
}
}

void main() {
  var mic1=Microphones();
  print(mic1.name);
  mic1.name="Yeti";
  mic1.color="black";
  mic1.model=26;

  print(mic1.name);
  print(mic1.color);
  print(mic1.model);
  print(mic1.printEverything());
  print(mic1.printint());
}

output:
null
Yeti
black
26
Yeti
 
26
null
```

i highly appreciate your replies/help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods in Dart retuns `null` by default if you are not returning anything (either by having an empty `return` in methods specified to return `void` or not having any `return` at all in methods returning `void` or a nullable type like `int?`).

But return-type in the method signature specifies how the caller of the method should see the value. And here we have `void` which is described in the Dart language tour as:

> A special type that indicates a value that’s never used.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program

So we specify `void` to signal to the user of our method, that the returned value should never be used. And the Dart analyzer and compiler will then try very hard to make sure you are not ending up using the returned value typed `void`.

### Advanced section for the curious

But that does not mean it is impossible to use a returned value specified to be `void` by the method signature:

```
void someMethod() {
  void someVoidVariable = 'Hey, I am a String!';
  return someVoidVariable;
}

void someOtherMethod() => 'Hey, I am also a String!';

void main() {
  print(someMethod() as String); // Hey, I am a String!
  print(someOtherMethod() as String); // Hey, I am also a String!
}
```

In the first example, we force Dart to see our `String` as `void`. That is completely fine since all types can be seen as `void`. We are then allowed to return this `void` value since `someMethod()` is suppose to return `void`.

The reason for this forcing is that Dart would complain about (which makes sense because what we are doing is very much stupid and should never be in a real program):

```
void someMethod() {
  return 'Hey, I am a String!';
  // ERROR: A value of type 'String' can't be returned from the function 
  // 'someMethod' because it has a return type of 'void'.
}
```

Or this since we can't cast to `void` using `as`:

```
void someMethod() {
  return 'Hey, I am a String!' as void; // ERROR: Expected a type name.
}
```

We are then casting that `void` back to a `String` to let Dart allow us to use the returned value in `print()` (since Dart otherwise would prevent us from trying to use the `void` typed value).

In the second example, I show the one of the reasons for why things are working like they does. In Dart, we can write these two method which are going to do the exact same (note I changed the return type to `String` for this example):

```
String someOtherMethod() {
  return 'Hey, I am also a String!';
}

String someOtherMethod() => 'Hey, I am also a String!';
```

So the second way is a shorthand for if we just want to execute a single statement and return its value.

But what about:

```
void someOtherMethod() => 'Hey, I am also a String!';
```

If we followed the traditional rules, this would not be allowed since we cannot return a `String` since we have typed `void`. But sometimes, we also want to use this simple syntax to just execute a method and don't want to care about what that method would end up returning.

E.g. this:

```
final someList = <String>[];
void removeStringFromList(String string) => someList.remove(string);
```

Where the `remove` method on `List` is actually returning a `bool` which indicate if the element was inside the list.

So Dart ignores this problem when we use the `=>` by just casting the result to `void` in this case. So in our last example, the returned `bool` is actually returned to the caller of `removeStringFromList` but because its type has been cast to `void`, the caller of `removeStringFromList` is prevented (in a lot of ways) from using the value.